# How would I create a function that determines whether the users input is one the words included in a vector

Tags: c++, function

I have been trying to create a game of hangman using functions. One that gets the users guess and another function that sees if the users guess is in the word that is created in the vector. Any help on how to get the playersGuess and how to create a function to see if that guess is the word would be appreciated. Code is below.

```
char playersGuess();    

int main()
{
//setup 
const int MAX_WRONG = 8;    //maximum number of incorrect guesses allowed

vector<string> words;       //collection of possible words to guess
words.push_back("GUESS");
words.push_back("HANGMAN");
words.push_back("DIFFICULT");

srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
random_shuffle(words.begin(), words.end());

const string THE_WORD = words[0];       //word to guess
int wrong = 0;                          //number of incorrect guesses 
string soFar(THE_WORD.size(), '-');     //words guessed so far
string used = "";                       //letters already guessed

cout << "Welcome to Hangman 2. Good Luck!\n";

//main loop
while ((wrong < MAX_WRONG && soFar != THE_WORD))
{
    cout << "\n\nYou have " << (MAX_WRONG - wrong);
    cout << " incorrect guesses left.\n";
    cout << "\nYou've used the follwoing letters:\n" << used << endl;
    cout << "\nSo far, the word is:\n" << soFar << endl;
    char guess = playersGuess();
    while (used.find(guess) != string::npos)
    {
        cout << "\nYou've already guessed " << guess << endl;
        playersGuess();
    }

    used += guess;

    if (THE_WORD.find(guess) != string::npos)
    {
        cout << "That's right! " << guess << " is in the word.\n";
        //update soFra to include newly guessed letter
        for (int i = 0; i < THE_WORD.length(); ++i)
        {
            if (THE_WORD[i] == guess)
            {
                soFar[i] = guess;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Sorry. " << guess << " isn't in the word.\n";
        ++wrong;
    }
}

//shut down
if (wrong == MAX_WRONG)
{
    cout << "\nYou've been hanged!";
}
else
{
    cout << "\nYou guessed it!";
}

cout << "\nThe Word was " << THE_WORD << endl;

return 0;
}

char playersGuess()
{
char guess;
cout << "\n\nEnter your guess: ";
cin >> guess;
guess = toupper(guess);     //make uppercase since secret word in uppercase
return guess;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) to search a `string` for a specific `char`

```
char guess;  // assume this is already set
std::string answer // this too

if (answer.find(guess) != std::string::npos)
{
    // Correct letter!
}
else
{
    // They were wrong, add a body part
}
```

The reason your code isn't working is because you never assign their guess to any variable. `guess` is a local variable that only exists within `playersGuess`. You'd have to do

```
char guess = playersGuess();
while (used.find(guess) != string::npos)
{
    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks I assigned the players guess to a variable and it works now. But I'm still struggling on creating the function that checks wherever the players guess is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something with the return of `playersGuess()`. You are inputting a char, but then effectively throwing it away:

```
char guess = playersGuess();
//   ^^^^^
while (used.find(guess) != string::npos)
{
    cout << "\nYou've already guessed " << guess << endl;
    guess = playersGuess();
//  ^^^^^
}
```

Comment: How would I go about using string::find in a function.